# Relate $det(A)$ to $det(B)$ after row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification, determinant

Suppose that $B$ is obtained from $A$ by replacing $R_1$ with $R_1 − (a_2R_2 + a_3R_3 + · · · + a_nR_n)$.
Give a formula for $det(A)$ in terms of $det(B)$ and $n, a2, a3, · · · , an$.

I think it works like this:
$R_1$ <-- $R_1 − (a_2R_2 + a_3R_3 + · · · + a_nR_n)$.

or $R_1$ <-- $R_1 − a_iR_i$ for $i$ not equal to to $1$

So $det(A)$ does not change from these operations. So, $det(A) = det(B)$

Comment: Scale row, scale det/swap rows, negate det/add rows, unchanged det

Comment: @Angelica so it doesn't change right?